# Keep form state when changing tabs in tabview PF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a tab view with two tabs. Each tab has a form like shown in that sample example :

```
    <p:tabView id="WorkSpace">
    <p:tab title="tab1" closable="true" id="tab_1" >
    <h:form id="formA">
    <h:outputText value="Reference: " />
                        <p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.reference}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
<h:outputText value="Age: " />
                        <p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.age}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
    <p:commandButton process="@this" action="#{testBean.testA}" value="OK">
    </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab2" closable="true" id="tab_2" >
    <h:form id="formB">
    <h:outputText value="Name: " />
                        <p:inputText  required="true" value="#{testBean.name}" requiredMessage="This field is required"/>
    <p:commandButton process="@this" action="#{testBean.testB}" value="OK">
    </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

My problem is I want to keep the form state when changing from tab to another, that's to say:
when I fill the input "reference" in formA, change tab to formB (without clicking on OK button) and then come back to formA the field reference should not be empty.

I understand that the form was not processed and no backing bean was updated,so I tried to use a remoteCommand that process formA onTabChange event in order to update the backing Bean :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="saveState" action="#{testBean.saveState}" process="@this" />
```

But, the form is being validated, (inputs age and reference should be filled). When trying to add immediate=true to skip validation, no field is updated on backingBean.

Is there any way to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: A combination of `dynamic="true"` and `cache="true"` should work, although that combo comes with its own nuances